# How can I keep track of when my repeating alarms goes off and update the set value?

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

The way the alarm manager currently works, I have to use:

```
//Set Alarm to Repeat
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilis, interval, pendingIntent);
```

to schedule a repeating alarm.

Currently, I'm pulling a time string from the database, converting it to miliseconds and setting this repeating alarm based on an interval in the database.

I am now wondering, what can I do so that when the alarm goes off, I can update the same time data in the database to a new future alarm date?

That way, I can pull when the next alarm time is from the database and display it on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve it using this way :
-set custom broadcast receiver at the time of Alarm goes off ,in side onReceive() save what  ever stuff you want in to preferences or sqlite .

Comment: Currently, I have a regular(?) broadcast receiver. What do you mean by custom broadcast receiver? What would be different about it? Can I just save time to db(sqlite) in onReceive() of my current receiver? If so, that means that when the alarm fires, the broadcast receiver onReceive is called and then I can update the db. My question is how do I know what time/date to save in db? Get the current system date time?

Comment: yes , you can insert what ev your data inside db inside onReceive method . and for custom broadcast receiver ,you have to just google it .so many links helpful links available there . ping me back if u can't catch me clearly

Comment: and I can update the current fields inside the database right? vs adding new ones? Do I need a custom broadcast receiver though?